# AFNetworking different cache settings for different content

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2 with:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                          diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

and I have different type of content:

- small content that changes rarely and has long expiration date
- small content that changes often and has small expiration date
- big images (100KB-200KB)

What if user will open 100 big images and these images will take all cache memory? I think big image will replace my small content even it hasn't expired yet. How can I fix it? Can I divide memory into 2 sections (first for small content, second for big images) or should I use different `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclasses with different cache policy for those types of content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cacheable URL requests use the same `NSURLCache`, whether you're using AFNetworking or not. Creating a new AFNetworking session manager won't make a difference.

`NSURLCache` will move older requests from memory to disk. It's not in the documentation, but I'd bet if stuff is getting purged, then `NSURLCache` will weigh frequency of access against the expiration date when deciding what to get rid of.

If need a guarantee that certain data is available, you should write it to disk yourself. Otherwise, you should let `NSURLCache` do its thing.

If you don't like that answer, one alternative is to use a library like `SDWebImage` (or roll your own), that doesn't use `NSURLCache` but implements its own separate caching mechanisms.  This way your large images won't interfere with your cache.